# changes to settings.py not updating

Tags: django

I am trying to get a django app to work on ubuntu with apache.

I am getting the error message "You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS."

I have made the changes to settings.py, but still get the error message.  I can see in the debug output that it looks like the changes I made to settings.py are not taking effect.  I have tried restarting apache ( /etc/init.d/apache2 restart) but still no help.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ALLOWED_HOSTS defined 2 times in settings.py ? It should be defined only 1 time.

Comment: I only have it defined once.  I tried removing the settings.py file, restarted server, but it behaved as if settings.py was still there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you managing your project files on the Ubuntu server directly or via FTP?

Comment: Have you added your server to the list of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`? `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['x.x.x.x']` If so, can you confirm changes have been applied to your project?

Comment: sorry i was a bit dense.  I uploaded the original files with ftp, but I am editing the files directly with vi.

Comment: Post the traceback or error message you are receiving. Is your project directory hierarchy formatted correctly?

Comment: DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'x.x.x.x'. You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://x.x.x.x/myapp/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value: 
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'x.x.x.x'. You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 105
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.5

Comment: I think the project directory should be ok.  I created my the project on my laptop where it works fine.  I then copied over to the server.  I am running Apache on Ubuntu.  It took some work to get mod_wsgi working but now I am stuck here.  I have tried touch on settings.py, but to no avail.  It looks like there is a copy of settings.py somewhere else that is being used.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Sometimes the formatting varies slightly from version to version. By default, Django looks for the settings.py file at location: `mysite/mysite/settings.py`. So, unless you have explicitly stated otherwise, Django will use the file located there.

Comment: hi t0bi,Thanks for your help.  It turns out I wasn't saving the the settings.py file. doh!

Answer (score 0):

Just add sudo before when running server script using python and it works like a charm. ex

> **sudo** python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000